What category does bliss belong to?
According to philosophers, is bliss an emotion? Or does it belong to a different category of thing?
Bliss is defined as according to the Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary, as being "1. complete happiness 2. paradise, heaven". This isn't a very good definition, which is why the hope of trying to categorize it beforehand might provide a clue as to what it means.
Emotion is defined as that which is emoted, according to the cognitive appraisal theory of emotions.

Why does the answer matter to you? What will change when you get an answer? I have no idea why you would ask this.

@ScottRowe I will become a little less ignorant than I am today. "I only know that I know nothing." - Socrates.

More philosophical mileage may come from examining bliss's synonym 'ecstasy'.  To be ecstatic is to be transported, a valence of spirit.
ecstacy ... from Greek ekstasis, from ek "out" (see ex-) + histanai "to place, cause to stand," from PIE root *sta- "to stand, make or be firm."
Moved out from where one stands.

Not sure if this is correct. You could be moved out from one stands into Hell, but nobody would call that bliss.

@Fomalhaut The meaning mainly refers to the movement not the destination. Just out, ek-.

That's outstanding!
